# Writing Spring Boot controllers with nested calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

New to Spring Boot here. I am trying a very simple app and testing it by going to `localhost:8080`.

This works fine:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = "application/json")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hi!";
    }
}
```

But when I try to call other functions from my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class MyController {

    private String sayHi() {
        return "Hi from a nested call";
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = "application/json")
    public String sayHello() {
        return sayHi();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

I tried using annotations for my called function, but still get the same. What is the cause of this error? It looks like the error description is not accurate here, is that right?

---

A follow-up related question. In my main class I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong with having other calls (anything that is standard Java) before the `run()` function? How about after it?

Comment: You're missing a return statement in `sayHello` v2. It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas added. I do have it in my actual code

Comment: Your "error" is a generic message stating you have no error handler configured. You _may_ have an actual stack trace somewhere in your logs; otherwise try configuring an error mapping handler to get one.

Comment: If you want work on checking/handling something before calling controller methods, after calling controller methods, you can check out spring interceptors which provides preHandle(), postHandle() and after completion(). https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Comment: Nothing wrong here. I tried your implementation . working good. Did you missed anything in question content?

Comment: Try running you spring boot jar with `--debug` to see if there's any output as to why it's going to the error URI. i.e. `java -jar target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --debug`